# Can I get acess to Monobehaivor properties through an interface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code:

```
IMovable movement;
void DisableMovementSystem()
{
     TryGetComponent(out movement);

     if (movement == null) return;
     
     movement.enabled == false;  //doesn't exist
                                     
}
```

What I would like to accomplish is to check whether a "`Monobehaivor`" component that inherits "`IMovable`" interface is enabled or not. Logically, I'm certain that if "`TryGetComponent`" method worked, than this is definitetly a **Monobehaivor**. But compiler doesn't. "movement" doesn't have "enabled" property. Is there any other way to get access to it?

I have an idea to create abstract method inside an interface, something like `void SetEnabledProp(bool enabled)` and use it. But maybe there is more elegant approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to see if a script inherits from `IMovable` and is also a `MonoBehaviour`?

You can do something like this

```
if(movement is MonoBehaviour) 
{
     // object is also a MonoBehaviour
}
```

Edit: Just so the answer is not in the comments, the solution OP was looking for was using the `as` keyword.

Comment: I'm trying to get access to Monobehaivor properties. Something like "where" keyword when creating generic types (class generic<T> where T : Monobehaivor). I'm confident, that interface inheritors are always Monobehaivors. So I'm trying to somehow specify to compiler that I'm working with them, even though their types are interfaces. Tryed your method, but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @bleatinterteiment Do you just want the properties of the type? Can you not use `GetProperties`? I am a little unsure of what you are trying to achieve. You can do `movement as MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: If you want to try to access something, you can easily use reflection with a `try catch` or one of the built-in `try` methods in reflection. I would need a bit more information as to what you are trying to achieve tho.

Comment: Thanks a lot! "as" keyword was exactly what I was looking for!